# Is there a term for referring to an organization by its city rather than by its name?

Tags: terminology, rhetoric, toponyms, metonyms, synecdoche

This happens specifically often in the technology press:

> - There's no point trying to ascribe motives to what Redmond [instead of "Microsoft"] does.
> - We'll see shortly if Cupertino [instead of "Apple"] thinks likewise ...

I'm certain its use is much wider though I can't think of many examples right now. Using "Detroit" as another name for the US auto industry is slightly wider:

> - Who says that Detroit does not sell cars Americans want to drive?

Anyway, I have a suspicion there is a name for this so what is it?

Comment: This is an interesting question... :|

Comment: Or "Washington reacted strongly to Moscow's actions last Tuesday, but for the meantime, Beijing's reaction remains cool."

Comment: "Houston, we have a problem."

Comment: My favourite (from James Bond?): “Vauxhall” to refer to MI6.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You may be looking for [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy).

If you're looking for other examples, governments are often referred to like this—at least, *Westminster* for the UK parliament, and *Washington* for the US government.  (In fact, looking up Westminster on Wikipedia was how I found *metonym*.)

Comment: Your examples *Westminster* and *Washington* are very good and made me think of another, *Fleet Street* for the British Press.

Comment: @hippietrail: And *Wall Street* for the financial industry :)

Comment: And *Madison Avenue* for the advertising industry. And any number of smaller ones, like *Jermyn Street* for the fancy men's shirt retailing industry.

Comment: *Hollywood* is perhaps the most famous city metonym.

Comment: @hippietrail - and *Fleet Street* is still commonly used even though there hasn't been a paper based there since 1989.

Comment: @e100: - and "Tin Pan Alley" for America's music industry, although the street that actually existed, or at least that use of it, is long gone.

Answer (score 22):

This is an example of [synecdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche).

In these examples, the company HQ is a part of the city as a whole. The city is being used as a metaphor for the company.

I wonder if these are being used in a slightly euphemistic way. It allows one to refer to the company without referring to directly, perhaps granting license to say something negative about the company with imagined impunity.

Comment: A nod to answers pointing to metonymy as the answer. Synecdoche is a form of metonymy.

Comment: Sometimes it's used as an aside eg Redmond or 'the chocolate factory' (for google) or just as shorthand, 'the pentagon' for the US military high command.

Comment: I really love this word but in Google searches *metonymy* came up much more often. I'll have to think about it some more...

Comment: @hippietrail: I wouldn't take popularity as an indicator of technical correctness!

Comment: @Rhodri: I took it more as statistical usage that popularity but it also seems that the part/whole relationship isn't the best fit. The fact that the kinds of examples I had in mind are included in lists of metonyms rather than lists of synecdoche has pushed the former to the best answer though I still consider the latter to be an acceptable answer.

Comment: note: *synecdoche* does not rhyme with *brioche*. It's sih-NEK-duh-kee

Answer (score 17):

To answer the question of difference between Dancrumb's [*synecdoche*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/is-there-a-term-for-the-use-of-place-names-to-refer-to-companies-based-there-eg/27173#27173) and John Bartholomew's [*metonym*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/is-there-a-term-for-the-use-of-place-names-to-refer-to-companies-based-there-eg/27172#27172), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy#Synecdoche) describes it thusly:

> When the distinction is made, it is the following: when A is used to refer to B, it is a synecdoche if A is a component of B and a metonym if A is commonly associated with B but not actually part of its whole.

Redmond and Cupertino are not *part* of their associated companies. Therefore, *metonym* is the more appropriate term. Furthermore, both appear on the [list of metonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_metonyms).

Comment: The people making the case for synecdoche are arguing the opposite, that the company headquarters is part of the associated town.

Comment: @Iceman: They are pretty interchangeable. _If_ you were to make a distinction, the distinction would be what is in my answer. The definition for _synecdoche_ does seem to include either pattern so... it is very possible Wikipedia is just being incorrectly pedantic on one specific page.

Comment: So is “pars pro toto” a synonym for synecdoche? My teachers at school could never agree, and the remark in the Wikipedia article is completely unintelligible to me.

Answer (score -2):

Placenames (specifically) in this context are *toponyms*, (the original sense, before the word referred to just 'place names in general'.  But *toponymy* is the study of place names, so not appropriate here: perhaps a new word needs to be coined for the trope.

(thanks for the suggestions)

Comment: @Tim, this is really more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @Tim, no offence meant, but I think this would be more appropriate as a comment rather than a full-fledged answer.

Comment: @Kit/Alain: do you really think so? It seemed to me a tentative answer (toponym) to the question asked, though the discussion seems to have veered off. I'd value your views.

Comment: Well, if it's an answer, you probably shouldn't say that it's not. :-)

Comment: @Tim, if you believe *toponymy* qualifies for an answer, then I'll have to disagree. Hence my down vote. As you actually seem to have found out on your own, toponymy is a science studying place names and more precisely focusing on their origin and meaning.  For instance in the sentence "Toponymy in England shows that many place names in the British Isles have a substrate of Celtic origin".