# Name given for use of capital cities to represent the government

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a term for referring to an organization by its city rather than by its name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/is-there-a-term-for-referring-to-an-organization-by-its-city-rather-than-by-its)

I can't come up with an example I actually read right now, but the capital city is sometimes used to represent the government. e.g "*The government stated that.....*", that would be "*London stated that.....*" or "*Official statements from London....*" (the 1st example may not be correct!).

There is a name given when using capitals to represent the government. What is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a term for referring to an organization by its city rather than by its name?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/27163/19644)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*metonym* is the word you're looking for.  Here's the definition from Google's dictionary:

noun /ˈmetəˌnim/ 
metonyms, plural

A word, name, or expression used as a substitute for something else with which it is closely associated. For example, Washington is a metonym for the federal government of the U.S