# "While this was happening, Beijing played its hand skillfully" Does it sound natural?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

> "While this was happening, ***Beijing played its hand skillfully***. Decades earlier, when China first embarked on its economic reform project, Deng Xiaoping, China’s leader until his death in 1997, urged subsequent generations of leaders to maintain a low international profile. "

I understand the meaning of the phrase that they took advantages of the situation. But does the phrase in bold sound natural, and are there any equivalent expressions?

Comment: As to your first question - yes, it sounds natural. As to your second, I think it would be helpful if you sorted out 'is' and 'expressions' and tell us how many you want.

Comment: It's very much idiomatic, for US English, at least.  There are other expressions, but nothing comes to mind that would fit better.

Comment: The expression in bold is an example of either synecdoche or metonymy, I never understand which unless I look them up.

Comment: Related: [Is there a term for referring to an organization by its city rather than by its name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/is-there-a-term-for-referring-to-an-organization-by-its-city-rather-than-by-its) and [What is the difference between metonymy and synecdoche?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/what-is-the-difference-between-metonymy-and-synecdoche)

Comment: That depends first on context and then on style… not grammar or semantics, anyway.

Comment: it is as natural as 2 peas in a pod!

Comment: yes, sounds nice to me and is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

The expression ***to play one's hand*** is idiomatic and very common. There is no need to substitute it with another unless its author wanted to appeal to a wider and more international audience, some of whom might be unfamiliar with its meaning.

Astonishingly, I did not find a dictionary reference that supported the game of cards inspired phrase. The closest I found was in Merriam-Webster's entry for [*hand*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hand)

> **9** a (1) : a player in a card game or board game (2) : the cards or pieces held by a player • *studied her hand*
>   b : a single round in a game • *lost the first hand but won the next two*
>   c : **the force or solidity of one's position (as in negotiations)** • *trying to strengthen their hand*

As a suitable alternative, the adjective **[shrewd](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shrewd)**, and its derivatives would be appropriate here. It carries a positive connotation and suggests that the person or persons are cautious and wary of making any mistakes, but ultimately they are thinking about gaining the best advantage for themselves, which I think is a common perception many westerners have of the Chinese government.

> While this was happening, Beijing **shrewdly** kept a low profile

With some tweaking, one could use any of the phrases suggested below

- displayed shrewd leadership
- [their low profile] was a shrewd political move
- a shrewd player

Cambridge Dictionary defines

> *shrewd*, *[shrewdly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shrewd)*, *shrewdness*: having or based on a clear understanding and good judgment of a situation, resulting in an advantage:

Answer (score 0):

There's an expression that is close to **play one's card** in meaning: [take an active role](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=play%20a%20hand).

> **Does God play a hand in our lives, or does He just watch?**

Your expression in bold also comes up in the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, 5th version:

> **play your cards right:** to say or do things in a situation in such a way that you gain as much as possible from it
>
> > *Who knows? If you play your cards right, maybe he’ll marry you.*

but it's used in another way.

In light of all that has been said, I wouldn't think that this idiomatic expression could be replaced with anything just as simple as it is. If so, the sentence would be a bit longer and even more complicated and wouldn't reflect what the original expression conveys.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idiom:

**be quick on the uptake** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+quick%2Fslow+on+the+uptake)

> understand things quickly/understand even simple things with
>   difficulty

As in:

> While this was happening, Beijing, being **quick on the uptake** as usual,
>   won the desired concessions.

Answer (score 0):

**versed in**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Versed)

> to familiarize someone with something by study or experience

As in:

> While this was happening, Beijing, being well **versed in** the art
>   'politics' remained silent.